# Moving to ARM from 8 bit AVR - how to take the 1st step?

Tags: arm, atmel

I've written code for AVRs for several years now and it seems like my needs are calling for a more powerful processor. Since Atmel Studio is the IDE I'm already using and my debugger also works with ARM MCUs, going with an Atmel device seemed like a no-brainer. The troubles began when I tried to actually start and write some code. AVRs have an endless amount of tutorials on forums such as avrfreaks.net but the Atmel ARM MCUs do not. To make things worse, Atmel offers, almost exclusively, code that is written with its ASF software framework which means that if I want to use it I have to adopt a pretty high level approach which I don't like in coding, as I am not entirely aware of what goes on under the hood.

My question is: if someone went through a similar path, what was the correct place to start and learn how to use these M3 MCUs without the ASF!

Comment: When using an Atmel or PIC, I never used the vendor-supplied function libraries.  With an ARM, however, most people do use the libraries.  I don't know about ASF, but if it is CMSIS-compliant, then the code is much more easily ported to other ARM controllers.  Also, other ARM developers will recognize the coding style... I started using the STM32F series controller and have never looked back. ST provides their "Standard Peripheral Library", which is CMSIS-compliant.

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0234a/index.html

Comment: You spend much more code setting up,enabling, and configuring peripherals and their clocks, but once you do they're  easy to use

Comment: @bitsmack I tried to learn Atmel ARM based as my first 32bit platform and was overwhelmed.  Then i stumbled onto stm32 and in your word i never looked back. Even that datasheets I find more easier to understand. I am not a fan of thier systemwork bench IDE but I do like Keil.

Answer (score 6):

No one forces you to use a peripheral library (ASF), you may very well code directly by toggling bits pretty much like on AVRs.  The ASF probably includes a file which contains all the registers' definitions so that you can code manually if you want to.

I also found that the peripheral library (for STM32, though) was not easy to use when I started, but once you understand how it works, you no longer need to care about low level idiosyncrasies of your device, so that your code is more portable and faster to develop.  I must admit that I prefer to code directly with registers, but there is a reason why ARM provide a kind of standard (CMSIS) for peripheral libraries and it is for ease of use: once you know an ARM, you know most of them, because the peripheral library wraps most differences behind a layer of abstraction.  You are better off taking a not-so-steep learning curve with the peripheral library provided for your chip (there are tons of examples on the Internet using peripheral libraries) than using register configuration, because you will end up with very few examples on the Internet.

Start with a small project and then try using peripherals using the library.  If you really want *not* to use it, then you probably will be on your own, but still, you can look in the ASF to see how they implemented stuff and reinvent the wheel if you want to.  Your call.

Comment: No one is forcing me to use ASF, that is true in the sense that no one puts a gun to my head but it does seems like the exclusive reading material I can get my hands on from Atmel. I understand the needs to simplify the coding process due to the increased complexity of the devices, however the lack of info on what goes under has its share or downs. For example, I tried to use the ADC, followed the app. note and at the end nothing happens (code compiles / no update to the variable). I don't know why and feeling helpless.

Comment: @user34920  did you turn on the clock to the adc?  Not remembering  to clock the peripherals is my most common error.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - using sysclk_enable_peripheral_clock()? I don't know how to find the parameter list. Is there also need to enable the ADC through the PMC?

Comment: Yup.  I don't  know your family, but the correct clock on the correct bus needs to be enabled.  I don't  know about enabling the adc on the pmc, but based on my limited stm32 experience, probably.

Comment: Start with a working example, and play with that.

Comment: @user34920  I think you understood my point well: nobody is threatening you to use ASF, but you will have hard time finding non ASF example.  It is up to you to decide whether you prefer the pain of having to understand how to use the peripheral directly using registers entirely by yourself or having to use the ASF and not understand the inner working with same intuition.  Either way, there's a steep learning curve.  In such situation, most people consider using the preferred method instead of what they'd like to do...

Comment: @user34920  I was in the same boat as you even wanting to only use Atmel Smart MCus but now i almost always use Stm32 because I hated All the learning material for Atmel involved ASF. Check out a course on udemy called mastering microcontroller with embedded driver development, basically he teaches you how to write your own drivers for gipo, i2c etc.. on 32bit stm32 by using the registers only. And once you understand that you can write code for any family any vendor because its all the same basic stuff. not to mention an stm32 board cost 2 bucks for 72Mhz and the programmer is 5 bucks.

Comment: @user34920 I love Atmel studio too and I use it still for AVR stuff , but Stm32 is great also, do not get stuck on an IDE or a vendor, like fanboy of sorts, be an egineer who can use any and all tools at his disposal. If anything just use the udemy course as a stepping stone to learn Atmel ARM, its only 10 bucks... (not my course or anything ) but i always reccomend it because I learned more from that course than any half ass tutorial online. There is nothing like a well structured and ordered set of videos to learn from.  if you have question shoot me a mssg. Amaya.6987 at gmail